# Make a split in the middle of a worksheet

Tags: excel

I am wanting to add a split vertically at Column I, basically splitting the worksheet into 2 halves.  I want to be able to scroll up and down on the left half while the right half doesn't move and then move over to the right half and scroll up and down while the left half doesn't move.

I have tried "Split" but it doesn't work how I would like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select View > New Window.

Then do <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> on window1, and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> on window2.

Tada..

Hope it solves.  ( :